# Traducir de consulta SQL a Eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, sql, eloquent

Hola soy nuevo en eloquent y laravel, tengo la siguiente consulta, la cual corre perfectamente desde phpmyadmin:

```
SELECT * FROM vips_categories JOIN vips_products JOIN vip_archivos WHERE  vips_categories.parent_id = 1 AND vips_categories.parent_id = vips_products.id AND vip_archivos.id = vips_products.img
```

Quise hacer lo siguiente:

```
 $query = DB::table('vips_products AS Producto)
->join('vips_categories as Categoria.','Categoria.parent_id','=',$categoria)
->join('vips_categories as Categoria','Categoria.parent_id','=','Producto.id')
->join('vip_archivos', 'vip_archivos.id', '=', 'Producto.img')
->select('*');
```

Pero al parecer es incorrecta, si alguien me podria ayudar a traducirla estaría muy agradecido

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primero que todo según veo, hay un error de sintaxis en  DB::table('vips_products AS Producto), falta cerrar ese string. Segundo, estás usando Query Builder mas no Eloquent. Si lo que necesitas es sacar esa consulta en Query Builder sería algo así:

```
$query = DB::table('vips_categories')
->join('vips_products','vips_categories.parent_id', '=', 'vips_products.id')
->join('vip_archivos', 'vip_archivos.id', '=', 'vips_products.img')
->where('vips_categories.parent_id', '1')
->select(['*']);
```

Comment: Hola @María Paulina, si en efecto, no conozco aún la diferencia entre Query Builder y Eloquent jaja, al ejecutar la consulta me da resultados diferentes, laravel me la regresa así:              select * from `vips_products` as `Producto` inner join `vips_categories` as `Categoria` on `Categoria`.`parent_id` = `Producto`.`id` inner join `vip_archivos` on `vip_archivos`.`id` = `Producto`.`img` where `Producto`.`parent_id` = 2

Comment: Los AS los acabo de agregar, igual

Comment: Hola. Lo que hice fue pasar la consulta SQL que dices funcionaba y la pasé a Query Builder. Debería lanzarte el mismo resultado. ¿Probaste la que te pasé? Si vas a trabajar con "AS" tendrías que utilizar el método DB::raw() y meter allí la sentencia con "AS".

Comment: Hola, si la probé si los alias y me da el resultado que te menciono de la consulta anterior, salen resultados diferentes.

Comment: Ya que no puedo reproducir el por qué te muestra resultados distintos, sugeriría en ese caso revisar la consulta, ya que la respuesta que escribí es la interpretación en Query Builder de la consulta suministrada; tal vez podrías revisar que no haya ambigüedades en el select tal vez, pero no sabría exactamente qué puede estar pasando. Cualquier dato extra para tener en cuenta sería de ayuda. Saludos.

Comment: Lo pude hacer  mediante las relaciones de laravel

Comment: ¡Excelente! Sí, Eloquent era una buena alternativa :)